# How to theming attachment views? I don't get nothing when I add elements to the tpl

Tags: 7, theming, views

I'm trying to theming the attachment glossary view

I have create the new tpl files for the elements I want to theming, but I don't get nothing.

I have clear cache several times, and also clean apc.

Any idea how to theming attachements?

Oskar

Answer (score 0):

you can use [display suit](https://drupal.org/project/DS) module and write some tpl file for your element you want to theme in a specific view mode you choose for your view and suggest it to drupal.

Comment: I try it, but nothings happens.